# Facebook send dialog link gets removed in recipient's inbox

Tags: facebook

I have a site that uses the `Facebook Send Dialog` for users to send messages to each other.  I call this:

```js
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    to: user.id,
    link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/'
});
```

This brings up the dialog and if the user clicks send, the message is sent.

That's great but the link (what Facebook calls the attachment) does not show in the recipient's inbox.  In its place is a warning box with the text

> "This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.".

I'm not sure why the link isn't working.  I don't think there is any permission involved because the Facebook documentation says that the Send Dialog does not need permissions.  Regardless my app already has the `publish_actions` permission.  Has anyone seen this before?